# how to read a generated XML from .Net Service in Java

Tags: java, android, xml

sorry for the silly question but this is y third week in android 
i created an application connected to MS SQL Server and got the data using .Net web service and read the XML result in Android using "REST" and it generated String contains the following XML data :

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Members">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="First_x0020_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Last_x0020_Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Email_x0020_Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <Members diffgr:id="Members1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ID>4</ID>
        <First_x0020_Name>Jane</First_x0020_Name>
        <Last_x0020_Name>Doe</Last_x0020_Name>
        <Email_x0020_Address>janedoe@yahoo.com</Email_x0020_Address>
      </Members>
      <Members diffgr:id="Members2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <ID>3</ID>
        <First_x0020_Name>Bob</First_x0020_Name>
        <Last_x0020_Name>Jones</Last_x0020_Name>
        <Email_x0020_Address>bob@yahoo.com</Email_x0020_Address>
      </Members>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

my QUestion is how to get this String and display the data in the XML in pretty Format ?!
Sorry again for  the silly Question but i have done many researches and they all call Files or URI or the URL

the thought i got is to get the string and create Class has Objects of member and return array list of this objects and display it in the interface , but i really don know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse an XML String, use a StringReader:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(yourXMLString));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("first-node");
```

And then continue with regular XML parsing, there are lots of examples. You can deal with the results in any way you like, display them, return the elements and values in arrays etc.